# Mapping file suffix to content type with ImageIO

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

I'm tidying up some code that uses [javax.imageio.ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html). I have the file suffix the user is requesting, e.g. jpg, and we transform a saved image then render it back to the user in the correct format.

Now I want to map the suffix to the MIME type. This is relatively easy to do with a quick switch, but given that ImageIO has both

- `static Iterator<ImageWriter>` [`getImageWritersBySuffix(String fileSuffix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getImageWritersBySuffix%28java.lang.String%29)
- `static Iterator<ImageWriter>` [`getImageWritersByMIMEType(String MIMEType)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getImageWritersByMIMEType%28java.lang.String%29)

it must know the mapping between suffix and MIME type, or the MIME type generated by a specific [`ImageWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html). Therefore there must be a way to get the content type from the writer that I'm about to use. But I don't see any methods or properties on ImageWriter that return the content type, or even the suffices.

Essentially I'm trying to complete the following block of code:

```
Iterator<ImageWriter> imageWriters = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix(type);
ImageWriter imageWriter = imageWriters.hasNext() ? imageWriters.next() : null;
if (imageWriter != null) {
    contentType = imageWriter. ???
}
```

Thanks! The brute force approach I guess is to get all of the MIME types supported then iterate through those until I find one that returns the same ImageWriter as the get-by-suffix call (if indeed it's easy to compare the results) but I'm hoping for something a little more elegant than that - I'd prefer a switch to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] mimeTypes = imageWriter.getOriginatingProvider().getMIMETypes();
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I did look at the ImageWriterSPI javadoc but didn't spot that in the inherited methods :-/